# How do I load a relationship from "belongsTo"?

Tags: laravel, relationship

So I have this model, 'Ticket' that contains (among other things) a "category_id" column.

To simplify, here is how my datas look:

#### Tickets table

| id | Title | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Issue #1 | 2 |
| 2 | Issue #2 | 4 |
| 3 | Issue #3 | 1 |

#### Categories table

| id | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Authentication |
| 2 | Account |
| 3 | Billing |

In my `Ticket` model, I've done the following:

```
/**
 * @return Category
 */
public function category(): Category
{
    return Category::firstWhere($this->category_id);
    // return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketCategory'); <-- how it was, can't eager load.
}
```

But I'm getting an `undefined function addEagerConstraints()`.

#### Edit: here is my controller:

```php
class TicketController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::with('category')->all();
        // dd($tickets);
        return view('tickets.index', compact('tickets'));
    }
}
```

I also tried with `hasOne` but this implies that "categories" needs a "ticket_id" column, which I want to avoid.

I'd like my models just to pick the category they are related to and nothing more.

What would be a solution here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not see belongsTo! beside share the controller code that cause that error please

Comment: I edited my question with the controller and the BelongsTo I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your category model, have the following code:

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
}
```

And add this in the ticket model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Add in the PHP 8 stuff you have already, and it should work!

Edit:
I saw you added more about how to load this properly. The code you already have in your controller should work with this as well. You'll maybe need to change the model class names in the methods I provided, but that should do the trick!

For more information about this type of relationship (one to many) read [this part of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: Goddamnit why did I struggle so much for THIS. Thanks a lot, I can only accept your answer in 5 minutes but thanks a lot for pointing the obvious to my blind self!

Comment: @Jaeger No worries! Happens to all of us. Staring at the same code for hours can make you blind to that type of problems ;)